# Is it possible to dynamically generate a sitemap.xml file using only PugJS?

Tags: javascript, pug

I've got a static website using Pug as the template engine (via Laravel Mix). For this website I would to generate a `sitemap.xml` file, based of the generated files. Is there a way to do this using only Pug?

Comment: as you mentioned, _Pug is a template engine_, so I don't really think you can retrieve all your website urls from a Pug template.

Comment: Yeah, I hope there is maybe a chance to find a list somewhere in Pug.

Comment: No, that's not what pug is for.